# Reset UIAppearance

Tags: ios, uiappearance

I create custom theme for my app using UIAppearance:

```
UITextField * proxy = [UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UIViewForm class]]];
[proxy setTextColor:[self getColor:textFieldColor]];
```

How do I reset back them to normal? When I assign nil color to setTextColor it will be actually blank. I would like to return to the my original colors. Is there a better way than setting up each color again?

Comment: Hmmm... Check it again? I just did a quick test, and `[proxy setTextColor:nil]` results in "resetting" the text color to its default black.

Comment: Not for me. Texts return to black correct but they are supposed to stay white on the original IB design. Same with buttons. Setting their background to nil makes the button transparent.

Comment: Hmmm... are you asking how to get back to a specific color you set in IB, rather than how to *reset* the appearance? Doubt you can do that without unloading/reloading the view.

Comment: It is not if I can reload. The point if I relod it will get nil colora.

Comment: Sorry, but this is confusing... I did a quick test - no problem. using `[proxy setTextColor:nil];` gives me the default color (black). You said *"Texts return to black correct but they are supposed to stay white..."*, but then you are also saying *"if I reload it will get nil color"*? So, does `:nil]` give you the ***default***? Or does it give you nil/clear? And, again, if you are trying to get back to a non-default color *after changing the color*, you'll almost certainly need to use the same process to set it back to your *non-default* value.

Comment: On iPhone X setting null on `tintColor` of `UINavigationBar`'s appearance proxy results in white button text, while on iPhone 6, it's working :(